# Date conversion issue in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a scenario where I have to get difference between the current date with the dates in a column from the `dataframe`. I am facing an issue when I took the current date  which is in `localDate format` and the date from `dataframe` are in date datatype.

Also I have tried to convert current day to string and and convert the data from `dataframe to string` but am not getting expected output as dates should be compared with date datatypes.

I have used the below code:

```
import java.time.LocalDate
val localDate = LocalDate.now 

def computeCarAge(importvoices:DataFrame): DataFrame = {

val computeCarAgeUDF = udf (
    (aged: Date) =>
      if (aged < localDate ) {
        "from0to1year"
      } else if (aged <= localDate) {
        "from1to2years" }
)
```

How to compare `java local date` to `spark.sql.date` which is in `(yyyy-MM-dd)` format?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the localDate of Java to Date datatype and then compare with your dataframe date. The sample code to convert LocalDate to Date Datatype is:

```
Date date = Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

The code sample is in Java but you can write the scala version of it :)

Comment: i need util date in yyyy-MM-dd format and with date datatype

Comment: you can do something like this:
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date)

Comment: it is storing as string.

Comment: val datef= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date)
datef: String = 2018-09-05

Comment: i need it as date datatype

Comment: once you get the string format of yyyy-mm-dd you can parse it to date format in this way:
Date dateModified = (Date)formatter.parse(datef)

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.